# How to update the SSRS Users table after a username change?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, reportserver

My user name has changed from `jdoe` to `john.doe` (for example). The reference in the `[dbo].[Users]` table shows my old user name, `jdoe`.

However, with my new user name, `john.doe`, the subscriptions fail to run and throw the error:

> Failure sending mail: The user or group name 'ABCDE\jdoe' is not
> recognized.Mail will not be resent.

The `[dbo].[Subscriptions].[OwnerID]` value references the `[dbo].[Users].[UserID]` for jdoe.

Can I simply change the `[dbo].[Users].[UserName]` value to my new username, leaving the `[dbo].[Users].[UserID]` and `[dbo].[Users].[Sid]` columns as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `MERGE` statement for this. Check the transaction on a rollback to test with first. You'll also need `UPDATE` permission on the `dbo.Users` table.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

;WITH 
users_list
AS 
(
    SELECT users_list.* FROM (VALUES
          ('DOMAIN\OldUser1', 'DOMAIN\New.User1')
        , ('DOMAIN\OldUser2', 'DOMAIN\New.User2')
    ) users_list ([UserName], [NewUserName]) 
)
, 
users_source -- don't add users that already exist to prevent duplicates
AS 
(
    SELECT 
          [UserName]
        , [NewUserName]
    FROM
        users_list 
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND [NewUserName] NOT IN(SELECT [UserName] FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users])
)
MERGE [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] AS T
USING users_source AS S
ON T.[UserName] = S.[UserName]
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET
  T.[UserName] = S.[NewUserName]
OUTPUT @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name], DB_NAME() AS [Database Name], $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;

GO
```

Comment: I took an easier route just to give it a try: I went to the "Security" folder and "Users" and tried to rename my current log in. It worked! All the errors have stopped and no other issues have become apparent. I'll keep the code handy, just in case!

Answer (score 1):

On your SQL Server, go to Security -> Logins. Then, rename the old username with the new username (just right click on it and select "Rename").

Next, go to the "Report Server" database, select the "Users" table, and update the "UserName" column for your old user.

This script should do the work:

```
UPDATE [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] SET UserName='domain\newUser' WHERE UserName='domain\OldUser'
```

The SSRS Subscriptions and other SSRS features should now work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried renaming the dbo.Users.UserName to the new DOMAIN/JDoe, but that still produces errors.

However, renaming the SQL Server's Security Username from DOMAIN/OldName to DOMAIN/NewName did the trick.